# Bring picturebox to front

Tags: c#

When I draw several images in a loop with some overlapping, like a deck of playing cards, I want the last card to be on top, to see the whole card. Now it's the first card that is visible. I wonder if there is a way to bring the first card to front or something equal?

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cardGui = new CardGui(i);
            cardGui.Location = new Point(10 + (i * 10), 10);
            panel1.Controls.Add(cardGui);   
        }
```

Comment: you said: " I want the last card to be on top" and also " I wonder if there is a way to bring the first card to front ". It confuses me. Could you correct?

Comment: I'm trying to correct it but I can't!? It should be the last card, sorry!

Comment: Could you concretize what you want. Or may be upload the image what you get for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code after your loop:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cardGui = new CardGui(i);
        cardGui.Location = new Point(10 + (i * 10), 10);
        panel1.Controls.Add(cardGui);   
    }
    cardGui.BringToFront();
```

> I want the last card to be on top

This code gives exactly what you asked

Comment: he wants to bring the first card to front if you use this code in the loop it's gonna do the same thing for all of them

Comment: It's the last card that I want to bring to front

Comment: Yes, it does, but then I don't get a nice row of cards, the last card cover some of the last cards

Comment: if you want the last card to be on top, of course it will cover other cards. Do you want the last card to cover first only?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`BringToFront()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) method or use [`SetChildIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) method of the parent's `Controls` collection.

> **`SetChildIndex`**: Sets the index of the specified child control in the collection to the specified index.
>
> **`BringToFront`**: Brings the control to the front of the z-order.

for a sample code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    cardGui = new CardGui(i);
    cardGui.Location = new Point(10 + (i * 10), 10);
    panel1.Controls.Add(cardGui);   
    panel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(cardGui, 10 - i); 
}
```

Comment: It's gonna do the same thing for every card he just wanna do that for the last card

Comment: @aliboy38: salam, My suggestion is using `BringToFront` or `SetChildIndex`; my codes are a sample.

Comment: this code won't work properly if there are already cards in the Controls collection.

Comment: @Ria salam. if you wanted to use that as a sample that's very good sample

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring the first card to front you should have 2 values for the card for example cardGui1 and cardGui2. the first one is only for being the front the others for completing the loop.

Try this :

```
const j =1;
cardGui2 = new cardGui2(j);
cardGui12.Location = new Point(10 + (j * 10), 10);
panel1.Controls.Add(cardGui2);
cardGui2.BringToFront();

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cardGui1 = new CardGui1(i);
            cardGui1.Location = new Point(10 + (i * 10), 10);
            panel1.Controls.Add(cardGui1);   
        }
```

Update :

I assume the last card index is 10. Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cardGui1 = new CardGui1(i);
            cardGui1.Location = new Point(10 + (i * 10), 10);
            panel1.Controls.Add(cardGui1);   
        }

const j =10;
cardGui2 = new cardGui2(j);
cardGui12.Location = new Point(10 + (j * 10), 10);
panel1.Controls.Add(cardGui2);
cardGui2.BringToFront();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's the last card I want to bring to front and I also like to just add cards without a loop and get the last card to front

Comment: i thought you want to bring the first card to front because you said "I wonder if there is a way to bring the first card to front" so if you want do this for the last card see the update.

Comment: @Artiom i said i assume that's 10 cards. he can use i<9 for the loop and use const j = 9. now it's 9 cards