# Change Z order of the control on edit mode in VS winform

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I can easily [bring to the front my specific win form control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981512/bring-picturebox-to-front) using this code snippet but it only works in runtime not in editor mode.

```
   lblAttendanceEmpName.BringToFront();
```

Is there any way avilable that i can arrange the controls order on editor?

Comment: Thanks silly me, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, it should just be  a case of

```
Rightclick -> Bring to Front
```

An image for specificity

[image]